# How does getting mysql's last insert ID work with transactions? + transaction questions

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, transactions, pdo

A two part question:

1. In my CodeIgniter script, I'm starting a transaction, then inserting a row, setting the insert_id() to a php variable, inserting more rows into another table using the new ID as a foreign key, and then I commit everything.

   So my question is: if everything does not commit before ending the transaction, how is mysql able to return the last insert ID, if nothing was even inserted? My script works (almost) perfectly, with the new ID being used in subsequent queries.

   (I say "almost" because, using the PDO mysql driver, sometimes the first insert that is supposed to return the insert_id() is duplicated--it get's inserted twice. Any idea why that would be? Is that related to getting the last ID? It never happens if using the mysqli or mysql driver.)
2. I first wrote the script without transactions, so I have code that checks for mysql errors along the way, such as:

   ```
   if(!$this->db->insert($table, $data)) {
       //log message here
   }
   ```

   How does this affect the mysql process once I wrapped all my mysql code in a transaction? It's not causing any visible errors (hopefully unrelated to the problem stated above), but should it be removed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To answer your first question...

When using transactions, your queries are executed normally as far as your connection is concerned. You can choose to commit, saving those changes, or rollback, reverting all of the changes. Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
insert into number(Random_number) values (rand()); 
select Random_number from number where Number_id=Last_insert_id();
```

//php

```
if($num < 1)
   $this->db->query('rollback;'); // This number is too depressing.
else
   $this->db->query('commit;'); // This number is just right.
```

The random number that was generated can be read prior to commit to ensure that it is suitable before saving it for everyone to see (e.g. commit and unlock the row).

If the PDO driver is not working, consider using the mysqli driver. If that is not an option, you can always use the query 'select last_insert_id() as id;' rather than the $this->db->insert_id() function.

To answer your second question, if you are inserting or updating data that other models will be updating or reading, be sure to use transactions. For example, if a column 'Number_remaining' is set to 1 the following problem can occur.

```
Person A reads 1
Person B reads 1
Person A wins $1000!
Person A updates 1 to be 0
Person B wins $1000!
Person B updates 0 to be 0
```

Using transactions in the same situation would yield this result:

> Person A starts transaction
>  Person A reads '1' from
>   Number_remaining
>   (The row is now locked if [select for update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) is used)
>  Person B
>   attempts to read Number_remaining - forced to wait
>  Person A wins
>   $1000
>  Person A updates 1 to be 0
>  Person A commits
>  Person B
>   reads 0
>  Person B does not win $1000
>  Person B cries

You may want to read up on [transaction isolation levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html) as well.

Be careful of deadlock, which can occur in this case:

> Person A reads row 1 (`select ... for update`)
>  Person B reads row
>   2 (`select ... for update`)
>  Person A attempts to read row 2,
>   forced to wait
>  Person B attempts to read row 1, forced to wait
>   Person A reaches [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) (default 50sec) and is
>   disconnected
>  Person B reads row 1 and continues normally

At the end, since Person B has probably reached PHP's `max_execution_time`, the current query will finish executing independently of PHP, but no further queries will be received. If this was a transaction with autocommit=0, the query will automatically rollback when the connection to your PHP server is severed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just to make sure I understood correctly, you mean to say that if I wrap all the mysql queries in a transaction, and the scenario you wrote above happens (two users both access a "winning" page at the same time), then it will go through only for one person? I would need to check if `number_remaining` is equal to 1 at the start of the transaction though, correct?

Comment: Correct. For the example I gave, you would also need to make sure that your isolation level was set to serializable or that a 'select for update' was used in order to lock the row on select. Update, delete and insert statements have different lock behavior depending on the isolation level as well. 
Using transactions for every query can lead to deadlock, so use them when it is vitally important for your data to be up to date and accurate.
I've updated my answer to include an example with transactions enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a great explanation! I was not aware of those mysql options you mentioned. I have a couple more questions, if you don't mind: 1. I looked up `serializable` in the mysql documentation, and it shows that it sets a `lock in share mode`. This does not actually prevent selecting the row. I think `select ... for update` should be used, correct (it blocks reading)? 2. In what cases can there be a deadlock using transactions? Why wouldn't the subsequent transactions simply wait their turn?

Comment: Correct, serializable locks in share mode, so for this example you would have to use `select ... for update`, I'll correct my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation of everything! I wish I could upvote you twice.